# How to know at runtime whether a Kony app was built in debug or release mode

Tags: debugging, cross-platform, temenos-quantum

I'd like to be able to determine programmatically whether the app was built in debug or release mode. I'd like to be able to write something like:

```js
if(isDebug) {
    //do domething.
}
else {
    //do something else.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using the Chrome debugger I was able to unearth the solution. There's a constant set during the build process which you can query in order to determine whether the app has been built in debug or release mode.

```js
if(kony.constants.RUNMODE === "debug" || appConfig.isDebug) {
    //do domething.
}
else {
    //do something else.
}
```